# heroku : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (64) '@'

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploying a java app to Heroku.

It use a enviroment variable such as postgres://foo:foo@heroku.com/hellodb to config database  in the spring applicationcontext.xml https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-mvc-hibernate#modify_database_configuration

I follow the document,config it,and set the DATABASE_URL use *set DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:huang@heroku.com/yan*（windows）.

But when i run it locally,i got a Error：
 *creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing fai
led; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (64) '@'*

my spring xml is this:

```
    `<bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
    <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url"
        value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
    <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
    <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
</bean>`
```

it seems the spring container cannot handle the '@' symbol ,but i really do not know how to deal it! I searched in google,but i got anything.

Does anyone know how to deal it ? thanks!

Comment: What version of spring are you using? Any chance you can post a complete sample app on github or similar place for easy repro?

Answer (score 0):

yeah，i fix it!!!

the official document has a error!!!

i just remove the "@" symbol,and it works

this spring xml is like this:

```
<bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
    <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
   <property name="url"
       value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + dbUrl.getHost() + dbUrl.getPath() }" />
   <property name="username" value="#{ dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
   <property name="password" value="#{ dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
</bean>
```

i will write a letter to report this error